# Ethereum Wallet sync completed and ETH balance went to 0

Tags: mining, wallets, javascript

I ran Ethereum Wallet for the first time on my Macbook Pro and, as it was syncing with TestNet, I selected **Develop -> Start Mining**. I saw the ETH balance increase steadily to 65 but then, it seemed that just when the sync completed, ETH balance went to zero, and has stayed at zero since then. I tried stopping and re-starting mining but that did not help.

Then, I noticed **Develop -> Toggle Developer Tools -> Wallet UI**. Clicked on that and noticed the following error in the console:

```
Failed to clear temp storage: It was determined that certain files are unsafe
for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file
resources. SecurityError
```

This seems to be related to the issue. Searching by this error message did not bring up any existing posts here, so I decided to post this question. Can anybody help throw some light on this?

**Update:** Just noticed that my ETH balance is now 6.88. Maybe the Javascript error can be ignored? Not sure why initially, balance was increasing in steps of 5 ether, then went to 0 and increasing very slowly now. My guess is that, by default, the syncing and mining started on the Main net and then I switched to Test net, it went back to 0. The low volume on Test net could be the reason for it taking a long time for any ETH balance to build up.

**Update 2:** I saw the following text today at https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Mining, which is more likely to be the correct reason of what I saw.

> Note that it will happen often that you find a block yet it never
>   makes it to the canonical chain. This means when you locally include
>   your mined block, the current state will show the mining reward
>   credited to your account, however, after a while, the better chain is
>   discovered and we switch to a chain in which your block is not
>   included and therefore no mining reward is credited. Therefore it is
>   quite possible that as a miner monitoring their coinbase balance will
>   find that it may fluctuate quite a bit.

I will wait for some time in case someone more knowledgeable has something more to add to this. If not, then I will convert this update to an answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is because Morden testnet has been decommissioned due to various stability issues.

You need to upgrade to Ropsten testnet.

https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/11/20/from-morden-to-ropsten/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.